# Python: String to list (without split)

Tags: python

I have Python lists saved as string representations like this:

```
a = "['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']"
```

and I'd like to convert that string to a list object. I tried to just load it directly, or use `list(a)` but it just splits every character of the string. I suppose I could manually parse it by removing the first character, removing the last one, splitting based on `,` and then remove the single quotes.. but isn't there a better way to convert it directly since that string is an exact representation of what a list looks like?

Comment: `a.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split(',')[0]`. Maybe also look at regex, it;ll be useful in the future ;)

Comment: `a[1:-1].split(",")` simple slicing also woks fine

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module

```
>>> import ast
>>> list_as_string = "['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']"
>>> _list = ast.literal_eval(list_as_string)
>>> _list
['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']
>>>
```